# Detect if two numbers are equal without disclosing further information

Tags: protocol-design

Consider the following scenario. Alice picks a number A; Bob picks a number B. Both A and B belong to a relatively small set X (by small I mean that X can be easily looped through: for intuition sake, imagine X to be the size of a deck of cards). I would like Alice and Bob to engage in a protocol that tells both if A = B. If A != B, then Alice should have no further information about B, and Bob should have no further information about A.

I wonder if this is possible? If X was very large, and assuming without loss of generality that A is prime, Alice could pick an arbitrary P prime larger than the largest value in X and send A * P to Bob. Bob could then try and factor A * P by B: if it works, then A = B. However, this obviously assumes that it is unfeasible for Bob to try all elements of X. If X is small, this assumption immediately falls.

Comment: This is called the [socialist millionaires' problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialist_millionaire_problem) by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is quite possible.

The obvious approach would be to have Alice and Bob perform a Balanced Password Authenticated Key Exchange (PAKE) protocol, with $A$ and $B$ being their 'passwords'.  If they come up with the same shared secret, $A=B$, and if they come up with $A \ne B$ and they don't learn anything else about $A$ and $B$

There are a number of PAKE protocols out there; see the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password-authenticated_key_agreement) for some of the more common ones.

One such way (which is simplified CPACE) to compare the values $a$ known to Alice and $b$ known to Bob  would be to select unrelated values $G$ and $N$ (I wrote this assuming elliptic curves; it can be directly translated to a modp group, except that the subtraction becomes a moduluar inversion) and:

- Alice selects a random value $r$ and computes $C = r G + a N$; she sends $C$
- Bob selects a random value $s$ and computes $D = s G + b N$; he sends $D$
- Alice computes $S = r (D - a N)$; Bob computes $T = s (C - b N)$; if $a=b$, then $S=T$; otherwise they're unrelated.

Alice and Bob can either send $S$ and $T$ to each other (if they trust the other side to be honest), or alternatively use those to generate encryption keys and do a simple verification protocol.